# Play framework job queue

Tags: asynchronous, queue, playframework

How does play handle asynchronous jobs when they are called using the now() method?

Are they executed immediately, or are they stored in a queue and processed by a fixed number of threads? What sort of control do we have over that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `now()`, your job is put into a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) via `submit()`. Since the executor uses a fixed-size pool, your job may end up being queued. Also, the pool is shared with your [scheduled jobs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/jobs#scheduling) , so you may have contention with them in addition to any jobs you spawned on demand.

You can adjust the size of the pool in your application's configuration, using the `play.jobs.pool` setting. The default value is 10.